# ParametricPlot with differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

in the beginning of the code I have:

```
 θ[t_] := Array[Subscript[θ, #][t] &, n];
```

Then after defining the differential equations and the constrains in EQ I can solve them and Plot them like this:

```
 s = NDSolve[EQ, θ[t], {t, 0, 100}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"} ]

 Plot[Evaluate[θ[t] /. s], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

But when I try a ParametricPlot, it no longer works:

```
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{θ[t] /. s, θ'[t] /. s]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Any idea why?
(I think it is in the θ'[t], but I dont know why)

EDIT (all code)

```
n = 2;
g = 9.8;
m = {};
l = {};
EOM = Array[# &, n];

For[i = 1, i <= n, ++i,
   AppendTo[m, 0.1];
   AppendTo[l, 0.5];]

\[Theta][t_] := Array[Subscript[\[Theta], #][t] &, n];

Ec[t_] := 0.5*Sum[(n + 1 - i)*m[[i]]*(l[[i]]^2* (Subscript[\[Theta], i]'[t])^2 + Sum[2*l[[i]]*l[[k]]*Subscript[\[Theta], i]'[t] *Subscript[\[Theta], k]'[t] * Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], k][t] - Subscript[\[Theta], i][t]], {k, 1, i - 1}]), {i, 1, n}];

Ep[t_] := -g*Sum[  (n + 1 - i)*m[[i]]*l[[i]]*Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], i][t]]   , {i, 1, n}];

Lagrangiano[t_] = Ec[t] - Ep[t];

For[i = 1, i <= n, ++i,
EOM[[i]] = 
    D[D[Lagrangiano[t], Subscript[\[Theta], i]'[t]], t] - 
    D[Lagrangiano[t], Subscript[\[Theta], i][t]] == 0]


thetainicial = Array[# &, n];
Dthetainicial = Array[# &, n];
For[i = 1, i <= n, ++i,
   thetainicial[[i]] = Subscript[\[Theta], i][0] == Pi/4;
   Dthetainicial[[i]] = Subscript[\[Theta], i]'[0] == 0]
EQ = Join[EOM, thetainicial, Dthetainicial];

s = NDSolve[EQ, \[Theta][t], {t, 0, 100}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"} ]

Plot[Evaluate[\[Theta][t] /. s], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Everything fine until this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[\[Theta]'[t] /. s], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{\[Theta][t] /. s, \[Theta]'[t] /. s}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Neither one works.

Comment: New EDIT. Thanks

Comment: Try  s = `Flatten@NDSolve[EQ,  {θ[t],  θ'[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, ...`

Comment: Doesn't change anything. The problem seems to by that θ'[t] equals zero always, but this shouldn't be happening

Comment: Without an expression for `Lagrangiano`, it is difficult to provide additional advice.

Comment: Ec[t_] := 0.5*Sum[(n + 1 - i)*m[[i]]*(l[[i]]^2* (Subscript[\[Theta], i]'[t])^2 + Sum[2*l[[i]]*l[[k]]*Subscript[\[Theta], i]'[t] *Subscript[\[Theta], k]'[t] * Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], k][t] - Subscript[\[Theta], i][t]], {k, 1, i - 1}]), {i, 1, n}];

Ep[t_] := -g*Sum[  (n + 1 - i)*m[[i]]*l[[i]]*Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], i][t]]   , {i, 1, n}];

                               Lagrangiano[t_] = Ec[t] - Ep[t];

Comment: Please put the code in the question in the proper order and provide values for all quantities, such as `n`.

Comment: All of the code is there now

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modifications provide what I think is the desired answer.

```
s = Flatten@NDSolve[EQ, θ[t], {t, 0, 100}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
```

to eliminate an extra `{}`.  Then, as before, `θ[t]` is obtained by

```
Plot[Evaluate[θ[t] /. s], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The other two plots require modified code:

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[θ[t] /. s, t]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic] 
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Transpose@{θ[t] /. s, D[θ[t] /. s, t]}], {t, 0, 10}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

[image]

`Transpose` is needed to pair each `θ'[t]` with the corresponding `θ[t]`,

Comment: YES!!!! Thank you!